# Java Regex: Match any word from pattern

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to implement a search function.
The user types a phrase and I want to match any word from the phrase and the phrase itself in an array of strings.
The problem is that the phrase is stored in a variable, so the `Pattern.compile` method won't interpret its special characters.

I'm using the following flags for the compile method:

> Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.LITERAL |
>   Pattern.MULTILINE

How could I achieve the desired result?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
For example, the phrase:

> "Dog cats donuts"

would result in the pattern:

> Dogs | cats | donuts | Dogs cats donuts

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split the user-specified phrase by `\s+` into, say, `arr`.
2. Build the following pattern:

   ```
   "\\b(?:" + Pattern.quote(arr[0]) + "|" + Pattern.quote(arr[1]) + "|" + Pattern.quote(arr[2]) + ... + "\\b"
   ```
3. Compile *without* the `Pattern.LITERAL` option.

In other words, if you want your patterns to match *words* in a user-specified phrase, you have to use **alternation** (the pipes) so that any one of those words can be considered a match. However, using the `Pattern.LITERAL` option makes the alternation operators literal—therefore you have to "literalize" just the words themselves, using the `Pattern.quote(...)` method. The `\\b` are **word boundaries** so that you do not match, say, a word in the user's phrase like "bar" when encountering text like "barrage".

---

**Edit.** In response to your edit. If you want to match the longest possible match, *e.g.* not "Dogs" and "cats" and "donuts" but rather "Dogs cats donuts", you should place the complete phrase in the beginning of the alternation series, *e.g.*

```
\\b(Dogs cats donuts|Dogs|cats|donuts)\\b
```

Comment: missing one ')' in the last part of the regex string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String regex = "\\b(" + phrase + "|" + phrase.replaceAll("\\s+", "|") + ")\\b";
```

In action:

```
String phrase = "Dog cats donuts";
String regex = "\\b(" + phrase + "|" + phrase.replaceAll("\\s+", "|") + ")\\b"; 
System.out.println(regex);
```

Output:

```
\b(Dog cats donuts|Dog|cats|donuts)\b
```